# Let $X$ be a such space that every map $f: X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous. Prove that $X$ is discrete.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a such space that every map $f: X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous. Prove that $X$ is discrete.

To show that $X$ is discrete I need to show that $\forall x \in X$ there exists $U_x$ such that $U_x \cap X = \{x\}$. Now by the problem statement I have that $f_i : X \to \Bbb R$ are continuous for all $i \in I$.

From continuity I have that $\forall x \in X: \exists U_x$ such that $f_i(U_x) \subset V_{f_i(x)}$ where $V_{f_i(x)} \subset \Bbb R$ is open.

How can I use this to get the result $U_x \cap X = \{x\}$? I'm a bit lost...

Comment: What is $U_x$? What are $f_i$? You're writing symbols without specifying. To show that $X$ is discrete, you need to show every singleton in $X$ is open (what you write seems very roundabout, maybe you're confusing discreteness of a space with discreteness of a subspace).  What you say under "From continuity" is actually an empty statement as written, unless you've chosen specific $V$. Since the hypotheses is that *every* $f$ is continuous, I suggest you think about how to pick an appropriate $f$ to derive something instead.

Comment: $U_x$ is an open neighborhood of $x$ and $f_i$'s are the maps that they're stating are continuous in the problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x\in X$ and consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f_x\colon&X&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&y&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }y=x\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$Since $f_x$ is continuous, there is an open neighborhood $U_x$ is $x$ such that$$y\in U_x\implies|f_x(y)-1|<\frac12\implies f_x(y)=1.$$But then $\{y\in X\mid f_x(y)=1\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$ (since it contains $U_x$). But $\{y\in X\mid f_x(y)=1\}=\{x\}$. So, $\{x\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$. This occurs for every $x\in X$, and this proves that $X$ is discrete.

Comment: Why not just say that $f^{-1}[(0,2)] = \{x\}$ is open by continuity as $(0,2)$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and $x$ is the only point mapping into it?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, that would have been shorter.